# clang-tidy check to require parentheses around compound expressions

Tags: c++, automated-refactoring, clang-tidy

I would like to catch cases like this:

```
if(a == 2 && b == 3)
```

and convert them to:

```
if((a == 2) && (b == 3))
```

I didn't see anything that sounded like this [here](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/list.html) - is there a way to enable this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no clang-tidy check that would do this transformation. The reason probably being that there is nothing wrong with the code you want to transform.

I don't even think that this transformation is something clang-tidy is intended for since this is just a question of coding style. Nowhere did I find a guideline that would prefer the first style over the second or vice versa.

You can write your own check but I don't think it's worth it. The only thing you can gain here is readability but even that is debatable at best.